# How to ignore a specific route in ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

What Is the proper syntax to put in the RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method in an ASP.NET MVC application if I want the app to ignore all urls that start with the word "score" like

> `http://myserver/score*.*`

?

In other words, any url that starts with the text "score" I want my app to ignore.

I tried:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("score*.*/{*pathInfo}");
```

I also tried several other combinations of this syntax but can't quite get it right.

Here is what I have so far in my RouteConfig. It's pretty much the standard stuff.

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Order", action = "Add", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want ASP.NET MVC to do when your ignored route is requested, return 404?

Comment: Can you show your complete route configuration please? To ensure something else is interfering...

Comment: Updated my question to show entire Routing config.

Comment: May not be the best solution but, you could probably do this with a custom global action filter.

Comment: Are you going to have multiple folders that start with the word "score"? If so, then explicitly enumerate the ignore route entries by folder name. If you try to generalize this too much (via a regular expression in the `IgnoreRoute`), then you run the risk of blocking any controller that starts with the word "score".

Comment: Try this: routes.IgnoreRoute("{*score}/{*pathInfo}", new { score = @"score*.*" });

Comment: @freshbm: If you post your comment as an answer I'd be more than happy to mark it as an answer. I changed it a bit by putting score*.* at the end, and it worked. I want to also ignore URLs to score.js or score.txt.

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo :) I will gladly put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place your score*.* as a regEx expression in IgnoreRoute:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{score}/{*pathInfo}", new { score = @"score*.*" });
```

For more general answers, you can use this pattern to ignore routes that you want:

```
Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*foo*}", new { foo = @"someregextoignorewhatyouwant"});
```

So for score.js and score.txt route you will add regEx that filters that routes.